# Remove figure number in subfigure references in caption

Tags: cross-referencing

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[Case A]{%                                                                                                                                                                                       
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}%                                                                                                                                                
    \label{fig:image_a}
  }\hfil
  \subfloat[Case B]{%                                                                                                                                                                                       
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}%                                                                                                                                               
    \label{fig:image_b}
  }
  \caption{Case A (\ref{fig:image_a}) and Case B (\ref{fig:image_b}).}
  \label{fig:images}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

The figure number in subfigure references in caption is superfluous. How can I remove it, formatting the caption as:

> Case A (a) and Case B (b).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its already provided by the author of subfig. You only need to replace your \ref with \subref.